# How to url rewrite subdomain to specific file?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, subdomain

How can I setup url rewrite to do this?

http://abc.example.com to http://example.com/myfolder/abc.aspx

Basically follow that pattern for any subdomain.

This is what I got so far but it isn't working.

`<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="subdomain mapping" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.example\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/myfolder/{C:1}.aspx/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>`